# Squares on custom typeface

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I am creating a `TypeFace` with this code:

```
setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/"+ fontName));
```

It is using `ttf` file to create this font.

When I try to use UTF-8 turkish strings to display it works on many devices, but in 
`Samsung Galaxy S3` it creates unwanted squares on `i` chars.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out there is an other character in input file

a sample bugged input is in here

```
<text>İngi̇li̇z-Çevi̇rmeni̇n-Notu</text>
```